# Safest way to remove USB drive on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, usb-drive, removable-storage

Is `umount $mountpoint` always enough to safely remove a single-partition USB drive on a modern GNU/Linux system? Or should I use `sync && umount $mountpoint && sync`, or perhaps `umount $mountpoint && udisks --detach $device`? I'd like to use the safest way possible, but on the other hand I don't want to introduce superfluous dependencies or delays into my program.

EDIT: [Does umount calls sync to complete any pending writes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345917/does-umount-calls-sync-to-complete-any-pending-writes) indeed answers a part of this question (whether `sync && umount $mountpoint && sync` provides any benefit over `umount $mountpoint`), but not the whole question (whether `udisks --detach $device` or some other command provides improved safety), so it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: SHort answer: `umount` is safe and doesn't need anything else, but of course, you have to check its return value to see if the command was effective.

Comment: Unmounting a USB drive only partially makes it safe to remove.  It stops I/O to the filesystem, but it doesn't power down the device, making it possible to remount the device.  It also doesn't flush any I/O cache to the device, so the data you *think* may be on the device, may not be.  In a gui, you'll often see an option to "Safely Remove" a USB device.  That option sync's first, then unmounts, then powers down the device.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [Eject USB drives / eject command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129282/29483):

> eject will work, but will not really "finish the job" regarding USB
> rotating drives.
>
> The best way to unplug a USB external hard-drive, after proper
> unmounting, is:
>
> ```
> udisks --detach /dev/sdb
> ```
>
> This usually causes the drive to spin down gracefully.

> EDIT: Also, as g.rocket points out, this command may be equivalent:
>
> ```
> udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
> ```

Comment: Does executing this command after unmounting improve protection against data loss/corruption or only reduce power usage?

Comment: You'd hope it never makes a difference, but I don't know. It does help in the sense that a spinning drive is more vulnerable (docs on mine say "don't move it"), & with a short thick cable it is very hard to unplug without also moving the drive around a bit.