# Immediately after 'fusermount -u; umount' sporadically fails with Target is Busy

Tags: unmounting, bind-mount

I've a script

pre-condition: `lsof /dir1` clear

```
#/bin/bash
...
fusermount -u /dir1/dir2   # unbind dir2
umount /dir1               # sporadically fails with 'Target is Busy'
...
```

- Why do I get sporadically a 'Target is Busy' error?
- Given I need to know the filesystem has unmounted before closing a VPN connection, what can I reasonably do about it?

Comment: Use `sync` before trying to umount and also make sure there are no more read/write operations onto target device.

Comment: @paladin As of this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345950/352601) `sync`ing is not necessary.

Comment: What do you intend to do once you've unmounted `/dir1`? If the answer is "nothing" then you could use `umount -l /dir1` quite safely. If you want to wait until the filesystem is unused because it's on a removable device (for example), you probably want a busy loop to wait for all open file descriptors on the filesystem to go away. Or use `unmount -l` anyway and wait for the unmount to action

Comment: @roaima Actually, I want to close a vpn-tunnel after the `umount`. So I guess, `umount -l ...` is not an option.

Comment: `lsof -f | grep ' [/]dir1'` would go some way towards finding the processes still using `/dir1` in some way (including the `/dir1/dir2` mount)

Comment: @roaima For testing, I repeatedly run the script `mount; bindfs` followed by `fusermount; umount`. 4 out of 5 tries it works fine and in one case there is this "Target is Busy". Shouldn't `fusermount -u` be finished before `umount` is started?

Comment: I don't know for certain. However, if you run the `lsof | grep` you should see what's holding the mount open. Armed with that information you (or we) can look at creating a solution to resolve the issue. It might simply be that you need to pause a little longer after the `fusermount` has supposedly finished, for example.

Comment: Read `man fuser lsof`. Use `sudo lsof +D /dir1`.

Comment: @roaima, @waltinator Strange enough, right now I'm unable to reproduce the behavior neither with nor without the `lsof` added to the script.

Comment: To me that sounds like you simply need a "short pause" between the `fusermount` and the `umount` to allow things to settle down. (I'd prefer a quantitative answer such as "_wait until all relevant processes have ended_" to a qualitative one such as `sleep 2`, mind.)